# Quantile interpretation

Tags: interpretation, quantiles, quantile-regression

If I have have the score for $q=0.9$, say $Y=y_{0.9}$. Does this mean that the probability of measuring a score $<y_{0.9}$ is 0.9?

Edit: Basically I have one dependent variable, $y$ (a type of score/performance metric). And another measure of an individual's characteristics, $x$, this is assumed independent. I have been told that the data is such that I need to use quantile regression (something about normality). This gives me various lines (quantiles) on $x$ versus $y$ plot. Say I fix myself at $x=x_0$ and then look at where that vertical crosses the $q=0.9$ line, this gives some value $y_{0.9}$. What is the interpretation of this value, both in terms of the data I have and in terms of what quantile regression is predicting?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "measuring a score" and on the characteristics of $Y$ (whether it be a random variable or a dataset), as well as what you mean by $y_{0.9}$ (this site has discussed at least nine different definitions!).  Please, then, give us a little more context and details.

Comment: I added some more details, hope it is clearer!